# How to store values in database once I created a new metabox in each of my products? How to change these values correctly using a function?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, meta

I have created a new meta box in each of my products using the following code  (pasted in functions.php):

```
/**
 * ADD A CUSTOM SECURITY FIELD
*/
function cfsf_create_custom_field() {
$args = array(
'id' => 'cron_function_security_field',
'label' => __( 'Cron Function Security Field', 'cfsf' ),
'class' => 'cfsf-security-field',
'desc_tip' => true,
'description' => __( 'Security field when providing automatic updates', 'cfsf' ),
);
woocommerce_wp_text_input( $args );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'cfsf_create_custom_field' );
```

**1) The field appears only for Simple products in the general tab - not variable ones - any ideas there?**

**2) When I insert any value - number or phrase (123 or "set_attributes") and click save, the value is not stored - it does not show up again.**

**Would you have any ideas how to store the values in database correctly?**

I wish to use the following command in fuctions to change these values automatically and then check for them - using update_post_meta and the "value" is always the function name (code chunk for better understanding):

```
private function set_custom_price($product) {
    if (!$product->exists()) {
        return false;
    }

    $product_price = $product->get_regular_price();

    if (($product_price > 0) && ($product_price < 401)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + ($product_price*(0.5)))/10) *10-1);
    } elseif (($product_price > 400) && ($product_price < 801)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + 120)/10) *10-1);
    } elseif (($product_price > 800) && ($product_price < 1101)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + 150)/10) *10-1);
    } elseif (($product_price > 1100) && ($product_price < 1601)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + 200)/10) *10-1);
    } elseif (($product_price > 1600) && ($product_price < 2001)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + 220)/10) *10-1);
    } elseif (($product_price > 2000) && ($product_price < 5001)) {
        $product->set_regular_price(ceil(($product_price + ($product_price*(0.15)))/10) *10-1);
    }

    update_post_meta($product,'cron_function_security_field','set_custom_price');
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Can you check: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-product-fields-woocommerce/ - Please write back if that will not help about storing the input value.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks a lot :-)